# jQuery Tabs - Ajax version

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I have my jquery ajax tabs running great. However I having problems getting/setting the content of an "input" on my selected Tab when the tab load.

This is what I have so far:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
             //$("#myinput").text('test');
                 $("#myinput").val('test'); <-- works 
            }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `html()` instead of `text()`?

Comment: Both are wrong. inputs are updated with val.

Comment: don't you have duplicated #myinput on page? (testing with multiple tabs and single template to load)

Comment: my bad! i messup on that one. Yes .val() works... sorry guys for that waste ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because an input's value is set with `.val()` not `.text()`.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
load: function(event, ui) {
         $("#myinput").val('test');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An `input` doesn't have `text()`, it has, instead, `val()`, therefore try using:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
             $("#myinput").val('test');
            }
    });
```

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you have to set #myinput as .val('test') not as .text('')